# Placing button on top of asp.net image control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

Is it possible to place a button on top of an Image control in a custom control ?

Comment: Do you mean in terms of Z-order or in terms of Y position?

Comment: I am new to asp.net :( . I have an Image control for displaying Image what I need is now place a button on the displayed image

Answer (score 0):

You can take Image button
like this

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgButton" ImageUrl="~/images/asc.gif" />
```

set your image url , this image button work same as normal asp button,
You can also get server side Click event of this button.